# In a struct definition, how do I refer to a type with a generic with two trait bounds?

Tags: rust

In the spirit of "learning by doing", I'm trying to build a little bioinformatics tool in Rust. I have a struct that should wrap around an [`IndexedReader`](https://docs.rs/bio/latest/bio/io/fasta/struct.IndexedReader.html) from the [bio](https://docs.rs/bio/latest/bio/index.html) crate. `IndexReader` has this signature:

```rust
pub struct IndexedReader<R: Read + Seek> {
    pub index: Index,
    /* private fields */
}
```

I want to create a struct that owns the reader, and allows me to iterate over fixed-size chunks of sequence. This was my first try:

```rust
pub struct IterableSequenceSegment {
    reader: IndexedReader, // <- something wrong here
    index_pos: usize,
    step_size: u64
}
```

But I get an error: `Add missing generic argument: <R>`

Since I don't know, and don't want to presume, the concrete type for `<R>` that is used when instantiating the IndexedReader, I presume I need to use a `Box<>` to denote that the concrete type of R is only known at runtime, right?

However, I do not get how to actually write that. I tried

```rust
pub struct IterableSequenceSegment<'a> {
    reader: IndexedReader<Box<dyn Read + Seek>>, // <- something very wrong here
    index_pos: usize,
    step_size: u64
}
```

But I get an error `only auto-traits can be used as additional traits in a trait object`. I could create a custom trait in *my* module like

```rust
trait R: Read + Seek {}

pub struct IterableSequenceSegment<'a> {
    reader: IndexedReader<Box<dyn R>>,
    index_pos: usize,
    step_size: u64
}
```

which seems to at least pacify the compiler - but I have no idea if that's the "right" thing to do? Is there a more "elegant" way to solve this issue? Why do I even need to refer to the trait bounds in the `Box`? As `Seek` and `Read` have no associated types, why does this even matter to the compiler?

Comment: Here's an advice: don't reach for `dyn` unless you really sure this is what you want. In this case, you don't. You want a normal, static generic parameter, i.e. `pub struct IterableSequenceSegment<R: Read + Seek> { reader: IndexedReader<R> , ...`.

Comment: But in that case, my whole `IterableSequenceSegment` would be a generic, depending on the way in which the `IndexedReader` reads it source file... I suppose that's the correct thing to do if I don't create the `IndexedReader` inside e.g. the constructor of my own struct 

Comment: Yes if you want to accept any reader (be generic over the type of the reader), a generic type parameter is usually the way to go.

Comment: And what is the problem with it being generic?

Comment: If you only need this for one specific type, e.g. `File`, you can also use `reader: IndexedReader<File>`.

Comment: *Is* the concrete type of `R` only known at runtime? When I started out in Rust awhile ago, I had the same problem. I was constantly thinking "Wow, all these type arguments that I can't possibly know at compile-time". But the fact is you *usually* do. In my experience, a solid 90% of applications of generics are statically known, and the remaining 10% can be `dyn`ed away conveniently when you encounter them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to make `IterableSequenceSegment` take an `R` argument as well:

```
pub struct IterableSequenceSegment<R: Read + Seek> {
    reader: IndexedReader<R>,
    index_pos: usize,
    step_size: u64
}
```

This approach is common in a lot of Rust code and pretty flexible.  I've seen types with several different generic parameters in code like Hyper (the HTTP crate), and usually things just work without too much effort because the compiler deduces the types.

You certainly can go with the boxing approach with the custom trait, which is sometimes required if you can't accept a generic type for whatever reason.  You gain some flexibility here at the cost of at least a little performance and optimization.  For example, if the compiler knew that `R` were a `std::io::Cursor<Vec<u8>>`, it might be able to do a lot of optimization here, assuming that your types do what their names imply.  That wouldn't be possible with your `Box<dyn R>`.

If you decide to go that route, you may find it convenient to implement the trait `R` for anything that implements `Read` and `Seek` (note the lack of the lifetime in my definition):

```
trait R: Read + Seek {}

impl<T: Read + Seek> R for T {}

pub struct IterableSequenceSegment {
    reader: IndexedReader<Box<dyn R>>,
    index_pos: usize,
    step_size: u64
}
```